# Render in Real Time? Fasten Render Times?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, optimization

i do love to use this software, for a lot of things, like faster modeling, and friendly interface;
The thing is, i work for a Dome System, so i have to Render 4K (4096x4096p) resolution frames at 60fps, and in fisheye format, so even little 30 seconds in 3D took three entire days, a LOT OF TIME, (and with basic textures/animation)
I've seen on plugins to other softwares like After Effects, that in 'Elements' you can lower the render times A LOT. Same with Cinema4D and AE implementation.
The thing is, before trying to jump into those mix of softwares, is there any way to fasten render times, in Internal, Cycles or any other possible rendering option? Even if its possible to make it nearly of real-time rendering?
I only use simple textures, maybe bump, not too much geometry because i don't like to use that much due to optimization, but render times is something that is actually killing my own job, because i can't preview somehow the animations i make the same day so it's like being animating things blind.
Please, if someone know a possible option, please tell me, i'm worried.

Comment: Have you tried Eevee yet? its still pretty buggy but it may help.

Comment: You should provide an example scene so that we can look into possible ways to optimize it.

Answer (score 2):

it depends of your gpu/workstation, gtx 1060 doesn't handle 4k well, you should try to reduce render samples , you should take a look to this tutorial made by Blender guru, aimed to get a smaller render time: [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gSyEpt4-60) , by the way if you want something closer to real time rendering, you can reduce samples in preview mode, then you could use rendered mode in blender

you could try:

rendered: 128

preview: 32 or 64

but be careful of it, the less samples, less quality you'll have
but you will have more shorter render times

[image]

[image]

[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHDMibsKKFA) is another tutorial to achieve similar "real time rendering" workflow  like evee engine used in last version of blender, but instead, in the oldest versions without the brand new real time rendering engine "evee" ,

hope this can be useful for you, cheers

Comment: Thank you, i'm going to try that option, also, i'm going to also share my computer specs if that helps too.